# How to use await inside caolan async?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, async.js

I would like to use `await` method inside the `async.Series`

Here is my node js code

```
const async = require("async");

async.eachSeries(myArr, function (arr, callback) {

    let test = await db.collection('coll').findOne({ _id: arr }); //I couldn't use await here

    callback(null, test);

}, function (err) {
    console.log("Done");

});
```

I have tried

```
async.eachSeries(myArr, async function (arr, callback) {

    let test = await db.collection('coll').findOne({ _id: arr }); //It not working here

    callback(null, test);

}, function (err) {
    console.log("Done");

});
```

And

```
async.eachSeries(myArr, async.asyncify(async(function (arr, callback) {

    let test = await db.collection('coll').findOne({ _id: arr }); //It not working here

    callback(null, test);

})), function (err) {
    console.log("Done");

});
```

Correct me If the approach is wrong or let me know how to achieve await inside the async each.

Answer (score 2):

As `async` [document](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/) said:

> Using ES2017 async functions Async accepts async functions wherever we
> accept a Node-style callback function. However, we do not pass them a
> callback, and instead use the return value and handle any promise
> rejections or errors thrown.

If you still pass the `callback` function as the second parameter of `eachSeries` 's callback function, it will not work as expected. Just remove
`callback` and return the result:

```
async.eachSeries(myArr, async (arr) => { // remove callback parameter
  const test = await db.collection('coll').findOne({ _id: arr }); // wait the response
  // ...
  return test; // return response
}, function (err) {
  console.log("Done");
});
```

Or just use `for...loop` instead of `eachSeries`:

```
// inside a async function
for (const i of myArr) {
  const test = await db.collection('coll').findOne({ _id: arr });
  // Do something with `test`
}

console.log("Done");
```

Answer (score 1):

Why mix callbacks with promises?

Right aproach will be use an async iterator Symbol.

If not first attempt would be valid

```
eachSeries(array, async function(arr, cb) {
   await ....
});
```